# Vuetify grid system issues in Nuxt across layouts, pages and components (+ background color issue)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, css-grid

I am trying to replicate this login page layout: [Mentor Cruise Login Page](https://mentorcruise.com/auth/login/)
Basically a 1/3 vs 2/3 split and a vertically centered login component.

I'm using my default.vue layout to manage whether or not the navbar/appbar are shown at all. Also use middleware to redirect to the authentication.vue page if no user is present. The logic all works. But the layout has me struggling. The Vuetify documentation is spotty or assumes lots of CSS knowledge I don't have. I tried reading up on CSS flexbox but it does not seem to translate as I would expect or maybe Nuxt is getting in the way with the parent-child relationship handling between layouts, pages and components.

If someone could let me know how I can recreate this layout and where this should go, that would be great!

Here are the elements that should create this top-down:

**default.vue** layout file:

```js
<template>
  <v-app id="youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ">
    <template v-if="isLoggedIn">
      <Navbar />
      <Snackbar />
      <Confirm />
    </template>
    <v-main>
      <Nuxt />
    </v-main>
    <Footer />
  </v-app>
</template>
```

**authentication.vue** page file

```js
<template>
  <v-container id="authentication">
    <v-row no-gutters fluid align="center">
      <v-col cols="4" class="info">
        <v-img
          :src="require('~/assets/XXX.png')"
          contain
          max-height="100"
          max-width="100"
        ></v-img>
      </v-col>
      <v-col cols="8">
        <client-only>
          <Login />
        </client-only>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  head() {
    return {
      title: this.title,
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    title: 'Authentication',
  }),
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.theme--dark.v-application {
  background-color: var(--v-background-base, #121212) !important;
}
.theme--light.v-application {
  background-color: var(--v-background-base, white) !important;
}
</style>
```

**Login.vue** component

```js
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row justify="center" align="center">
      <v-col cols="12" sm="8" md="6">
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title class="headline">
            <span v-if="this.isLoggedIn">Welcome {{ this.displayName }}</span>
          </v-card-title>
          <v-card-text>
            <div v-if="!this.isLoggedIn">
              <div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>
            </div>
            <div v-else>
              <p>You are logged in with {{ this.email }}.</p>
            </div>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import { createNamespacedHelpers } from 'vuex'
const { mapGetters } = createNamespacedHelpers('user')

export default {
  name: 'Login',
  mounted() {
      //firebaseUi stuff that works
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      isLoggedIn: 'getIsLoggedIn',
      displayName: 'getUserDisplayName',
      email: 'getUserEmail',
    }),
  },
}
</script>
```

What I have:
[image: Current Page Layout Screenshot]

What I have (Console):
[image: Firefox Console Output]

What I want:
[image: Mentor Cruise Login Page Screenshot]

If someone can then tell me how the hell I set the col background color using the vuetify theme config from `nuxt.config.js` that would be amazing. I tried classes, I tried the color prop..nothing works.

// Edit1: Added console/CSS screenshot as per @kissu's request
// Edit2: Added [codepen](https://codepen.io/RobSteward/pen/OJWPapo)

Comment: Since it's a CSS issue, CSS code (through devtools screenshots or alike) or a [repro] would be nice !

Comment: Fair point @kissu. Added the [codepen](https://codepen.io/RobSteward/pen/OJWPapo)

Comment: I've gotten so far as to get the full-height. Now but the alignment/justify still don't work [Updated Codepen](https://codepen.io/RobSteward/pen/OJWPapo)

Answer (score 0):

Solved this in a hackey way by wrapping the elements contained in the 2 columns in a container again. I DO NOT think this is how you should do it. Probably upsetting the CSS gods. But it works.

```js
<v-container id="authentication" fluid fill-height pa-0>
    <v-row no-gutters style="height: 100%" id="authentication-row">
      <v-col cols="4" class="primary darken-2">
        <v-container fluid fill-height justify-center>
          <v-img
            :src="require('~/assets/logo.png')"
            contain
            max-height="100"
            max-width="100"
          ></v-img>
        </v-container>
      </v-col>
      <v-col cols="8">
        <v-container fluid fill-height justify-center>
          <client-only>
            FirebaseUI component
          </client-only>
        </v-container>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
```